# Given $ 0 \neq f \in \mathbb C[x]$ prove that it has no double roots if and only if $gcd(f,f') = 1$

Tags: polynomials

> Given $0 \neq f \in \mathbb C[x]$ prove that $f$ has no double roots if and only if $gcd(f,f')=1$

How do we approach this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to notice before tackling this problem is that over $\mathbb{C}[x]$ every polynomial can be *completely factored* (i.e, factored to product of polynomials of degree 1). So your proof has 2 ways:

- $f$ has no double root $\Rightarrow \gcd(f; f') = 1$
  If $f$ has no double root, that means when we factor $f$, we'll get:
  $$f(x) = \beta \prod_{i = 1}^n (x - \alpha_i)$$
  Where $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$, and $\alpha_i \neq \alpha_j$, for every $i \neq j$ (i.e, the set $\{ \alpha_i \}$ is pairwise different). Now you can try to differentiate $f$, and prove that $f; f'$ share no common divisor apart from an invertible constant. 
   **Hint:** $f$ has a divisor $x - \gamma$ iff $f(\gamma) = 0$.
- $\gcd(f; f') = 1 \Rightarrow f$ has no double root. This can be done by *Proof by Contradiction*, assume that $f$ does have double root, then try to prove that $\gcd(f; f') \neq 1$.

Comment: I understood the second part, but not hte first part. Why the $\beta$?

Comment: For example, when you factor: $2x^2 + 10x + 12 = 2(x+3)(x+2)$. The $\beta$ is basically the leading coefficient of $f(x)$.

Comment: but $\beta$ divides them... so it is their GCD, no?

Comment: Yes, but $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$, so it's divisible. So saying "their GCD is $\beta$" is the same as saying "their GCD is 1". What we're proving here is that they have NO other divisors apart from some divisible polynomial, which mean their gcd is 1.

Comment: Np man, I'm glad I can help u. :*

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ has a double root in $z_0$. Then $f(z) = (z-z_0)^2 p(z)$ where $p \in \mathbb C [z]$. Then $f'(z) = 2(z-z_0)p(z) + (z-z_0)^2 p'(z) = (z-z_0) q(z)$, $q\in \mathbb C [z]$. You should be able to finish this.

Comment: I went to user49685's way and used this to prove the second direction.
The first direction is my problem. If $f$ has no double roots then $gcd(f,f')=1$